How to make a custom C# Automapper for a groupBy LINQ query
I am new to using the AutoMapper library for my specific use case.
The data flows from stored procedure model in repository to service where it gets mapped to a dto to return to the frontend.
This is the model:
 [NotMapped]
 public class CashOrder
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

     public DateTime? DateFinalised { get; set; }

     public string? ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

     public int DenominationOptionId { get; set; }

     public decimal? FaceValue { get; set; }

     public int? NumberOrdered { get; set; }
 }

This is the DTO
 class CashOrderDto
    {
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateFinalised { get; set; }

        public string? ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<DenominationDetailsDto> DenominationDetails { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<DenominationDetailsDto>();
    }

The DenominationDetailsDto has a list of the DenominationOptionId, FaceValue and NumberOrdered that is linked to the specific order.
The issue I am facing is that I get my data from a stored procedure that combines tables to get a list of the orders and their denominations.
the data has multiple orders where the DateCreated, DateFinalised and ReferenceNumber are all the same, the denomination details are what differs from row to row (because one order can have many denominatons.)
How can I do something like this using automapper? Is it even possible?
            return model
                .GroupBy(cashOrder => cashOrder.Id)
                .Select(cashOrderGroup => new CashOrderClearanceDto
                {
                    DateCreated = cashOrderGroup.First().DateCreated,
                    DateFinalised = cashOrderGroup.First().DateFinalised,
                    ReferenceNumber = cashOrderGroup.First().ReferenceNumber,
                    DenominationDetails = cashOrderGroup.Select(cashOrder => new DenominationDetailsDto
                    {
                        DenominationOptionId = cashOrder.DenominationOptionId,
                        FaceValue = cashOrder.FaceValue,
                        NumberHeld = cashOrder.NumberOrdered
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList(); // or FirstOrDefault for getting one specific item.


I've tried multiple ways, but the issue I find with automapper is that I cannot take the whole list of objects (you will always get a list of the model from the stored procedure) and combine them into one field based on the value.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is similar to: LINQ GroupBy Aggregation with AutoMapper. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The difference is that their People have the list already while mine does not. I am trying to get the list. Think of it as going from a list of records to one record with a list of related denominations for each record.
